# Swift equivalent to `[NSDictionary initWithObjects: forKeys:]`

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

Is there an equivalent for Swift's native `Dictionary` to `[NSDictionary initWithObjects: forKeys:]`?

Say I have two arrays with keys and values and want to put them in a dictionary. In Objective-C I'd do it like this:

```
NSArray *keys = @[@"one", @"two", @"three"];
NSArray *values = @[@1, @2, @3];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: values forKeys: keys];
```

Of course I can iterate with a counter through both arrays, use a `var dict: [String:Int]` and add stuff step by step. But that doesn't seem to be a good solution. Using `zip` and `enumerate` are probably better ways of iterating over both at the same time. However this approach means having a mutable dictionary, not an immutable one.

```
let keys = ["one", "two", "three"]
let values = [1, 2, 3]
// ???
let dict: [String:Int] = ["one":1, "two":2, "three":3] // expected result
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of **Swift 4** you can create a dictionary directly from a 
sequence of key/value pairs:

```
let keys = ["one", "two", "three"]
let values = [1, 2, 3]

let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(keys, values))

print(dict) // ["one": 1, "three": 3, "two": 2]
```

This assumes that all keys are different, otherwise it will abort
with a runtime exception.

If the keys are not guaranteed to be distinct then you can do

```
let keys = ["one", "two", "one"]
let values = [1, 2, 3]

let dict = Dictionary(zip(keys, values), uniquingKeysWith: { $1 })

print(dict) // ["one": 3, "two": 2]
```

The second argument is a closure which determines which value "wins"
in the case of duplicate keys.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use the Swift equivalent of `initWithObjects:forKeys:`

```
let keys = ["one", "two", "three"]
let values = [1, 2, 3]
var dict = NSDictionary.init(objects: values, forKeys: keys)
```

Comment: Note that with this approach your `dict` will be of type `NSDictionary` and not `[String: Int]`.  You would have do force downcast the to `[String: Int]` like this: `NSDictionary.init(objects: values, forKeys: keys) as! [String: Int]`

Comment: I'm aware that I use that, but it only works for keys conforming to `NSCopying` and `AnyObject` objects. Swift dictionaries also work for primitive types like `Int` in the example above or `enums`, `structs` etc. I don't want to use `NSDictionary` but Swift's native `Dictionary`

Comment: In this case the `Int` are converted to `NSNumber` automatically, as you can test with `print(dict.allValues.first?.dynamicType)`

Comment: Ah, I understand your requirement now. @JAL 's answer would be suitable for that.

Answer (score 3):

Working pure Swift solution with structs.  Use `zip` to iterate through your two arrays as a tuple, and then create a dictionary for each key, value in the tuple.

```
struct SomeStruct {
    var someVal: Int?
}

var keys = [String]()
var values = [SomeStruct]()

for index in 0...5 {
    keys.append(String(index))
    values.append(SomeStruct(someVal: index))
}

var dict = [String : Any]()

for (key, value) in zip(keys, values) {
    dict[key] = value
}

print(dict) // "["4": SomeStruct(someVal: Optional(4)), "2": SomeStruct(someVal: Optional(2)), "1": SomeStruct(someVal: Optional(1)), "5": SomeStruct(someVal: Optional(5)), "0": SomeStruct(someVal: Optional(0)), "3": SomeStruct(someVal: Optional(3))]"
```

You could also use `forEach` on `zip`:

```
var dict = [String : Any]()
zip(keys, values).forEach { dict[$0.0] = $0.1 }
print(dict) // "["4": SomeStruct(someVal: Optional(4)), "2": SomeStruct(someVal: Optional(2)), "1": SomeStruct(someVal: Optional(1)), "5": SomeStruct(someVal: Optional(5)), "0": SomeStruct(someVal: Optional(0)), "3": SomeStruct(someVal: Optional(3))]\n"
```

Comment: That was also my solution, I should've added it to my question. The downside is that you end up with a mutable dictionary in this case.

Comment: @orkoden Ah I see.  I added a solution that uses `map` which is a little less verbose.  Hopefully that works for your needs.  I'll keep thinking of how to create an immutable dictionary for you.

Comment: You don't even need `Array(Zip2Sequence(keys, values))` using `for (key, value) in zip(keys, values)` is enough.

Comment: @JAL, you should probably also use `forEach` instead of `map`.  `map` is for transforming the values in the array, while `forEach` will just iterate over them.  It's probably not a huge deal in this case, but it's a good rule in general.  `zip(keys, values).forEach { dict[$0.0] = $0.1 }`

Comment: Thanks @MikeS, love these improvements.

Comment: @orkoden re your edit: I'm using `Any` not `AnyObject`, which means I can use structs and value types in my dictionary.

Comment: I accepted the other language because it returns an immutable object, thus answers my question. I would however prefer using the approaches in this answer because it's easier to read.

Comment: @orkoden thanks for following up, wish I had a better answer, but this is the best I could do.

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner, using `zip` and `reduce`:

```
let dict = zip(keys, values).reduce([String:Int]()){ var d = $0; d[$1.0] = $1.1; return d }
```

You can shorten the `reduce` expression by defining the `+` operator for a `Dictionary` and a `tuple`:

```
func +<K,V>(lhs: [K:V], rhs: (K, V)) -> [K:V] {
    var result = lhs
    result[rhs.0] = rhs.1
    return result
}

let dict = zip(keys, values).reduce([String:Int](), combine: +)
```

Comment: Defining `+` as the operator to use is not very meaningful. Any other function name would be more self explanatory.

Comment: On one hand `+` has semantical meaning here, as it adds a new element to the dictionary, on the other it can also replace instead of adding so its effect might not always be cumulative. I personally find it meaningful enough; it can only be me, though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let keys = ["one", "two", "three"]
let values = [1, 2, 3]

func createDict<K:Hashable,V>(keys: [K], values:[V])->[K:V] {

    var dict: [K:V] = [:]

    // add validity checks here by yourself !
    // and return early, or throw an error ...

    keys.enumerate().forEach { (index,element) -> () in
        dict[element] = values[index]
    }
    return dict
}

let dict = createDict(keys, values: values)
// ["one": 1, "three": 3, "two": 2]

let dict2:[Int:Any] = createDict([1,2,3,4,5], values: [true,"two",3.4,5,[1,2,3]])
// [5: [1, 2, 3], 2: "two", 3: 3.4, 1: true, 4: 5]
```

what is the difference if it is compared to zip solution?
hard to say ... for me the zip type annotation is the biggest issue

```
let a:Zip2Sequence<[Int],[Any]> = zip([1,2,3,4,5], [true,"two",3.4,5,[1,2,3]])
var d:[Int:Any] = [:]
a.forEach { (key, value) -> () in
    d[key] = value
}
print(d)
// [5: [1, 2, 3], 2: "two", 3: 3.4, 1: true, 4: 5]
```

but enumerate solution is also a little bit quicker