# Immutable dictionary initialization in swift

Tags: swift

I would like to create an immutable dictionary from an array of structs.  Is there a way to directly do this in the language?  I know it can be done via a temporary mutable dictionary.

```
class Foo {
    let key: Int
// ... other stuff
    init(key:Int){ self.key = key }
}

let listOfFoos : [Foo] = []

var dict = [Int:Foo]()
for foo in listOfFoos { dict[foo.key] = foo }
let immutableDict = dict
```

or by using NSDictionary if Foo is an object

```
let immutableDict2 : [Int:Foo] = NSDictionary(objects:listOfFoos, forKeys: listOfFoos.map{$0.key}) as! [Int:Foo]
```

Comment: As far as I know, it can't be done. Workaround is create a function to return a dictionary. Inside the dictionary create a mutable dictionary and then return it

Answer (score 4):

Although Swift does not currently have functionality for constructing dictionaries bypassing a mutable dictionary, you could do it in a closure without a loop, like this:

```
static let listOfFoos : [Foo] = [Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)]

static let dict = { () -> [Int:Foo] in
    var res = [Int:Foo]()
    listOfFoos.forEach({foo in res[foo.key] = foo})
    return res
}()
```

This syntax is somewhat tricky, so here is a short explanation:

- `() -> [Int:Foo] { ... }` creates a parameterless *closure* that produces a dictionary `[Int:Foo]`
- `var res = [Int:Foo]()` creates a *mutable* dictionary that is later assigned to an immutable variable `dict`
- `listOfFoos.forEach({foo in res[foo.key] = foo})` replaces your `for` loop
- `()` after the closing curly brace invoke the closure right away, producing the result at initialization time.

Comment: It can be more concisely written using reduce as : let dict = listOfFoos.reduce([:]){$0[$1.key]=$1}

Comment: @BobCarver Which version of Xcode are you using? This does not compile for me in Xcode 7.3. I am getting "cannot assign through subscript, it is read-only"

Comment: @BobCarver You cannot do that, as the closure arguments are immutable. You'll have to assign `$0` to a `var` if you want a mutable version, such as shown in [the answer to the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34927789/2976878). Although by that point, `forEach` is just as concise and IMO more readable.

Comment: @originaluser2 Thank you !

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I was wrong it should have been let dict = listOfFoos.reduce([Int:Foo]()){var v = $0; v[$1.key]=$1; return v} as mentioned by originaluser2 - The readability leaves much to be desired