# Swift equivalent to NSDictionary initWithObjects:ForKeys

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

```
 NSArray *keys = @[@"one", @"two", @"three"];
 NSArray *values = @[@1, @2, @3];
 NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: values forKeys: keys];
 if user.isEligible() {
    [dict setObject:@"Hi" forKey:@"Eligible"];
 }
```

I already saw the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927057/swift-equivalent-to-nsdictionary-initwithobjects-forkeys), but that is not what i am looking for

I need to store `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary` in Swift and i need the exact translation of the `initWithObjects:forKeys` function

I want this `dict` to be mutable so that i can add objects to it like i add inside the `if-condition`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your convenience initializer in an `extension` ad use this:

```
for (key, value) in zip(keys, values) {
        self[key] = value
}
```

The zip function basically returns:

> A sequence of tuple pairs, where the elements of each pair are
>   corresponding elements of sequence1 and sequence2.

Answer (score 1):

The Swift literal dictionary syntax is as follows:

```
var dict: [String: Int] = ["one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3]
```

Comment: This is manually assigning one by one. Is there anyway to assign array of keys and array of values?

Comment: I misunderstood, sorry. I guess the answer you linked to gives answers to this. What is not suitable in your case?

Answer (score 1):

There is no literal equivalent in Swift.

You can create an `NSDictionary` and cast it to Swift `Dictionary`. The `var` keyword makes it mutable.

```
let keys = ["one", "two", "three"]
let values = [1, 2, 3]
var dict = NSDictionary(objects: values, forKeys: keys as [NSCopying]) as! [String:Any]

if user.isEligible() {
    dict["Eligible"] = "Hi"
}
```

But since keys and objects are created with literals anyway I recommend native syntax

```
var dict : [String:Any] = ["one" : 1, "two" : 2, "three : 3]
```

The explicit annotation `[String:Any]` is only needed if other types as `Int` will be added.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to add an extension to Swift's `Dictionary` type to add a convenience initialiser that accepts an array of keys and an array of values.

```
extension Dictionary {
    init(keys: [Key], values: [Value]) {        
        self.init()
        for (key, value) in zip(keys, values) {
            self[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Test it out:

```
let keys1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let values1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
var resultDict1 : [Int: String] = Dictionary(keys: keys1, values: values1)
// Result [5 : "e", 2: "b", 1: "a", 3: "c", 4: "d"]
```

By using `zip` internally the initialiser can deal with the fact that there may be a mismatch in the lengths of the `keys` and `values` arrays:

```
let keys2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let values2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
var resultDict2 : [Int: String] = Dictionary(keys: keys, values: values)
// Result [5 : "e", 2: "b", 1: "a", 3: "c", 4: "d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You also use like this because of swift typeSafe language..

```
let param = ["key1" : "value1",
             "key2" : "value2",
             "key2" : "value3"]
```

If you want same you can make your function like this..

```
let keys = [1,2,3,4]
let values = [10, 20, 30, 40]

var dict:[Int:Int] = [:]
keys.enumerate().forEach { (i) -> () in
    dict[i.element] = values[i.index]
}
print(dict) // [2: 20, 3: 30, 1: 10, 4: 40]
```

for Generic

```
func foo<T:Hashable,U>(keys: Array<T>, values: Array<U>)->[T:U]? {
    guard keys.count == values.count else { 
       return nil 
    }
    var dict:[T:U] = [:]
    keys.enumerate().forEach { (i) -> () in
        dict[i.element] = values[i.index]
    }
    return dict
}

let d = foo(["x","y"],values:[1,2])    // ["x": 2, "y": 1]
let dn = foo(["a","b"],values:[1,2,3]) // nil
```