# Is there a way to map an array of strings to an array of images?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm not sure if this is even possible but lets say we have an array of strings and need to match them up with a corresponding array of images. Like :

```
["Patriots", "Broncos", "Cowboys"]  =  [pat.png, bronc.png, cow.png]
```

I've tried with the map function but it doesn't seem to work:

```
let footballArray = ["Patriots", "Broncos", "Cowboys"].map({return [pat.png, bronc.png, cow.png] })
```

Any help solving this issue is appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use a Dictionary?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to set something like that up

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927057/swift-equivalent-to-nsdictionary-initwithobjects-forkeys But as Luk2302 suggested, you may want to review the basic collection types.

Comment: have you solved you problem?

Comment: Not exactly, I just made a custom class with the parameters needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dictionary like this from both sequence.

```
let a = ["Patriots", "Broncos", "Cowboys"]
let b = ["pat.png", "bronc.png", "cow.png"]

var footballDict: [String : String] = [:]

zip(a, b).forEach { footballDict[$0] = $1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try 
`let footballArray = [String : String] = ["Patriots" : "pat.png", "Broncos" : "bronc.png", "Cowboys" : "cow.png"]`

Or view [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can add the extension to your strings using `.map`

```
let footballArray = ["Patriots", "Broncos", "Cowboys"].map({ (value: String) -> String in
        return value + ".png"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about how to combine two arrays into one, you can use `zip`:

```
struct Team {
    let teamName: String
    let imageName: String
}

let teamNames = ["Patriots", "Broncos", "Cowboys"]
let imageNames =  ["pat.png", "bronc.png", "cow.png"]

let teams = zip(teamNames, imageNames).map { (teamName, imageName) in 
    Team(teamName: teamName, imageName: imageName)
}
```

That yields an array of `Team` objects, built using elements from those two arrays.