# SWIFT 5.1 Merge 2 arrays of different data types?

Tags: arrays, swift, array-merge

FOR SWIFT 5.1

How do you get an array of strings to merge with an array of integers?

stringArray: ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]

intArray: [ 1, 2, 3]

The result I am looking for is a list where the format would be String:Int

Tom: 1

Dick: 2

Harry: 3

Comment: You can use zip function.

Comment: Compare [Swift equivalent to `[NSDictionary initWithObjects: forKeys:]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927057/swift-equivalent-to-nsdictionary-initwithobjects-forkeys).

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you have to chain some awesome Higher Order function as like below:

```
let name = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]

let id = [ 1, 2, 3]

let dict = zip(name, id).map { [$0.0 : $0.1] }
                        .reduce([:]) { $0.merging($1) { (current, _) in current } }

print(dict)
```

Comment: Note that this can be simplified using [`init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127165-init) or [`init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127161-init).

Comment: In your solution, the compactMap is not needed, and the reducing is more efficiently done with `reduce(into:_)`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by this:

```
var intOne: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var stringArray: [String] = ["a","b","c","d"]

var dictionary: [Int: String] = [:]

for (index, element) in intOne.enumerated() {
    dictionary[element] = stringArray[index]
}

print(dictionary)
Output: [2: "b", 3: "c", 1: "a", 4: "d"]


extension Dictionary {
    public init(keys: [Key], values: [Value]) {
        precondition(keys.count == values.count)

        self.init()

        for (index, key) in keys.enumerated() {
            self[key] = values[index]
        }
    }
}
```