# How to deal out 2 different length arrays by the value?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Think of a company, employees work in different capacities. Employees will be employed according to their capacities. There should be similar capacities for every day.

I want the array1's values ​​in the days array to be equally distributed.

For example: Thursday -> 2 item and 5 value, Friday -> 1 item and 5 value
Saturday -> 1 item and 6 value, Sunday -> 2 item and 6 value.

Let it be distributed with similar numbers.

I have 2 array like this:

```
let days = ["Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
var array1: [T] = [T(name: "a", value: 3),T(name: "b", value: 2),T(name: "c", value: 5),T(name: "d", value: 1),T(name: "e", value: 6),T(name: "f", value: 4)]
```

How can I deal out array1 objects to days array?

I tried this:

```
var arrayValueTotal = 0
for t in array1{
   arrayValueTotal = arrayValueTotal + t.value        
}


var upperLimit = Double(Double(arrayValueTotal)/Double(days.count)) // This will get value per day. 22/4 = 5.5


for i in (0...days.count-1){ //Handling the days
   for j in array1{ 
         if j.value >= Int(upperLimit){ //handling the array1's value


         }else if j.value < Int(upperLimit){
                    

         }
    }
}
```

Desired result like:

```
    let combinedResult = [("Thursday": [T(name: "a", value: 3),
                                       T(name: "b", value: 2)]),
                          ("Friday":   [T(name: "c", value: 5)]),
                          ("Saturday": [T(name: "e", value: 6)]),
                          ("Sunday":   [T(name: "f", value: 5),
                                       T(name: "d", value: 1)])]
```

Here is the Class T:

```
class T {
    var name:String
    var value:Int
    init(name:String, value:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

How can I get that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn’t valid syntax.

Comment: @Alexander updated syntax.

Comment: What is `T("a":3)` supposed to be?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson reupdated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927057/swift-equivalent-to-nsdictionary-initwithobjects-forkeys ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift equivalent to \`\[NSDictionary initWithObjects: forKeys:\]\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927057/swift-equivalent-to-nsdictionary-initwithobjects-forkeys)

Comment: @Larme No, I see but that topic is not for me

Comment: I misread, sorry. It's becaue you didn't indented your target result. After seeing it, I don't understand the logic. What's the grouping logic? And you target result is an array of KeyValuePair, or rather Tuples??

Comment: I think this is answerable in its fixed form. I’m voting to reopen.

Comment: you can try to use 
let  = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(array1, array2))
should give you something close to what you were looking for
the results will look like the following:
["Cumartesi": [T(n: c, v: 5), "Cuma": [T(n: b, v: 2), "Perşembe": [T(n: a, v: 3), "Pazar": [T(n: d, v: 1)]
basically your results will be a dictionary.
hope it helps

Comment: @AvivFrenkel yes I was try it but my array1's count is 4 and array2's count is 6. It will deal with the what object's class T value.

Comment: @Alexander Can you try? If you find correct function, you can copy paste them. I really need help

Comment: @BorderFree On second reading: I have no idea what this is asking, because I don't understand what "While distributing the objects, I have to distribute them according to their "T Class's v" values." means. I don't see a pattern between the input and the output. You're going to have to be more detailed in explaining what you're trying to do.

Comment: @BorderFree You should also translate all the identifiers, strings, comments, etc Most of your target audiance here doesn't speak Turkish, so you'll want to use English if you want your question to get any attention/interaction.

Comment: You are doing a sum of ALL the elements (through `v` property) in array2. So, how can an element later be superior to it if you have only positive value? I still don't understand the logic. Could you say for each element of `array2`, why it should go we each element of `array1`?

Comment: @Alexander the question updated and reopen. Any idea?

Comment: @Larme the question updated and reopen. Any idea?

Comment: I almost got the logic, but `f,4` was changed into `f,5`? and why `d,1` is at the last item? It though it was: iterate the days, put the first items from array1 until the sum of their value is greater than 5, then, put the next elements of it into the next day, etc. But if that's the case, why is `d,1` at the end?

Comment: I edited the way you present `combinedResult` to make it clearer. Please keep that format.

Comment: @Larme 'f 4' or 'f 5' it doesnt matter. The important point is how it distributing same things.

Comment: Well it is important. Because I got `[T(name:a, value: 3), T(name:b, value: 2)]), ("Friday", [T(name:c, value: 5)]), ("Saturday", [T(name:d, value: 1), T(name:e, value: 6)]), ("Sunday", [T(name:f, value: 4)])]`
` as I understood your logic, BUT it's not the expected result. So yes, if there are exception in the logic, they need to be explained. If you make half assumption, you'll get half working code. And if tomorrow someone who has the same issue found your question, how he/she supposed to know that's the same logic you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if I understood correctly, let's start by separating `array1` according to `limit` (that you calculated yourself):

```
var array1: [T] = [T(name: "a", value: 3),
                   T(name: "b", value: 2),
                   T(name: "c", value: 5),
                   T(name: "d", value: 1),
                   T(name: "e", value: 6),
                   T(name: "f", value: 4)]

let reducedArray = array1.reduce(into: [[T]]()) { result, current in
    guard var last = result.last else { result.append([current]); return }
    if last.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.value }) < limit {
        last.append(current)
        result[result.count - 1] = last
    } else {
        result.append([current])
    }
}
```

Then `reducedArray` is:

```
[
  [T(name:a, value: 3), T(name:b, value: 2)],
  [T(name:c, value: 5)],
  [T(name:d, value: 1), T(name:e, value: 6)],
  [T(name:f, value: 4)]
]
```

Then

```
var final: [(String, [T])] = []
for i in 0..<min(days.count, reducedArray.count) { //If the count aren't equal, what to do with the left values?
    final.append((days[i], reducedArray[i]))
}

print("Final: \(final)")
```

With final being:

```
[
 ("Thursday", [T(name:a, value: 3), T(name:b, value: 2)]),
 ("Friday", [T(name:c, value: 5)]),
 ("Saturday", [T(name:d, value: 1), T(name:e, value: 6)]),
 ("Sunday", [T(name:f, value: 4)])
]
```

Comment: Really great solution. Respect.